# Github: Main page search bar ... how do I remove automatically popping up repositories when I click on search bar

Tags: git, github, search, repository, history

I want to delete my search history in my github.  After I login, to my account, I see the search bar in the top left corner of my page.

[image]

Once I click on the search bar, it pops up a bunch of repositories that I may have previously searched or accidentally saved.  I want them to be removed so that nothing shows up when I click on that bar.

How can I do that?

Comment: Good question. I tried cleaning the cookies and session/local storage and that didn't help. So I guess this is kept server side.

Comment: I tried that as well... my searches are still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is entirely managed on GitHub side.

That is from [May 2018](https://github.blog/changelog/2018-05-24-jump-to/):

> ### Search and Jump to
>
> The search bar at the top of each page has been redesigned to help users quickly navigate to team pages, repositories, and projects that were recently visited.
> If you click the search bar (or press `/`) you will be presented with quick “jump-to” options in the search dropdown based on their recency.
> These options are currently limited to repositories, teams, and projects—and you can also continue searching for these projects within the search bar.

You would need to [contact GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) for confirmation, and requesting a cleanup of that list.